# Set up remote camera monitoring on Android OS without user input

Tags: root-access, camera, rom, operating-system, background-process

Bringing [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077856/set-up-remote-camera-monitoring-on-android-os-without-user-input?noredirect=1#comment137645871_78077856) over from stack exchange as it was suggested I ask here instead.

I'm developing a personal project app (NOT for Play Store) to run on an old pixel phone I have. Here are my requirements

1. On boot, I want to automatically launch my app
2. The app should open a live camera feed and collect images at some interval
3. The app should stay alive indefinitely until a user explicitly kills it
4. All this needs to happen with NO user input

Nice to haves, but NOT required

5. The app should be able to function without the screen on

Now, I've successfully rooted my device to remove as many hurdles as I can. I got my app to launch on BOOT_COMPLETED, etc. But I'm hitting walls with the camera. I know the camera is not allowed to run in a background service. I was considering trying to force my app to be a system app, but I'm not sure if that let's me use the camera in this way either. The other option is to run the app in the foreground, but that requires a user to explicitly allow it to run continuously or else the OS kills it. But this will potentially trigger and run when I'm away, so I won't be there to hit play.

This is all like "spying app 101" stuff so that's probably why Android has put up so many roadblocks. But this isn't for other people. I have complete control of my device and will use it on my own property. I can do whatever custom ROMs people suggest, but I've not worked on any Android OS system code before so I'm hoping not to do that. However, if that's the only way, please let me know if you have any suggestions on where to start.

What is best way to achieve my high level goals here? Literally any architecture or strategy to do this is fine so long as it meets my requirements above.

Comment: Have you checked if the phone is supported by one if the common Linux distro? Your requirements do not really match with Android. A working Linux distro if available would simplify everything.

Comment: What an awesome tip! I did look into some alternative mobile OS's, but most seemed to be based on Android OS (which is itself based on linux, no?) Do you have specific distros in mind?

Comment: I noticed our regular user suggested to repost this here. Just to clarify the scope to avoid wrong expectation, this site focuses on power users and end-users POV, who are not necessarily developers. So, while the community might explain the technicalities about Android OS (including the system restriction imposed by Android, etc.), specific coding-related solution is considered off-topic and might be better to be continued on SO. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the confusion. Any and all insights are appreciated if anybody has them. Otherwise, no worries. Thank you

Comment: I know that Ubuntu and Debian provide images for Pixel devices, you can check if there are images for your device. Technically Android bases on Linux, however some libraries and a lot of other parts of the system architecture are different so directly running Linux programs can be quite challenging.

Comment: Really appreciate your help @Robert. However, I haven't been able to find any widely supported / up to date Ubuntu or Debian distros for mobile. The most promising I across were PostmartketOS and Ubunutu Touch, but neither support devices newer than 5+ years old. There's also this reddit thread talking about lack of solid mobile linux options (https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/175ghbp/porting_mobile_linux_distributions_to_pixel/)

However, I could be missing something obvious, so please let me know if you're aware of anything :)